# User Stories associated with a release

Tags: rally

This has likely come up before but I didnt have any luck finding it, is there a good way to pull a list of user stories associated with a release into an xml datasource?

Something like this (but this doesnt work)
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.33/hierarchicalrequirement?(release = somerelease)&fetch=true&pagesize=200

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it is supposed to be like this:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.33/hierarchicalrequirement?query=(release = https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.33/release/somereleaseid)&fetch=true&pagesize=200

Comment: You can also use relative refs in your query to shorten it a bit:

        https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.33/hierarchicalrequirement?query=(release = /release/12345)&fetch=true&pagesize=200

Answer (score 0):

You're close with your query. You need to add the `query` parameter and query against `Release.Name`, something like this:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.35/HierarchicalRequirement
?fetch=true
&query=(Release.Name = "my release name")
```